# What's a good way to calculate agreement between examiners when the measure is binary?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-data, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation, sensitivity-specificity

I want to assess ability to identify tumor types in humans vs. a computers. There are 7 tumor types. I am interested in calculating agreement between the human examiners but I am not sure the best way to go about it. I have only ever seen ICC used in continuous measures, but there is no order to tumor types. One option is to assess agreement between examiners using a binary (0=incorrectly identified, 1=correctly identified) but I do not know how to calculate that.

Comment: Maybe (adjusted) Rand Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option is to calculate Fleiss’s kappa (or Cohen's kappa if there are only two examiners) using the categorical response data of what each examiner guesses is the correct tumor type.

https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/fleiss-kappa-in-r-for-multiple-categorical-variables/